# webView android

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to make a simple WebView in my activity and I keep getting a "webpage not available" page in my android browser on the virtual device as well as an actual device.

I've looked though some samples online as well as the example in my book but I believe something is still missing.  Any help would be appreciated.  Code is below. `wv` is referencing a webview object in the main.xml file.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.amazon.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `INTERNET`-privilege to your Android Manifest?

Comment: I have not!  I'll try it now.

Comment: Wow!  I can't believe I missed that detail...it's step 1 :/  Thanks for the help it did the trick :)

Comment: Add a Custom Webview Client Class and implemet shouldOverrideUrlLoading(Webview u,String url) method,otherwise activity manger takes the control.

Answer (score 3):

For an android *webView* you need to keep 4 things in mind to make it work perfect.

1. Give the necessary *permission* to access internet in your android *Manifest.xml*
2. Import necessary libs like *webclient* and *webchromeclient* in your *YourActivity.java*
3. Enable *javascript* if you are going to show a webpage which needs java support.
4. Copy and paste all the image files you use in your webView to all the "*drawable*" folders in "*res*" folder of your project.

I've given you the complete code from Manifest to Activity.java. It works perfect. All the best..!

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.yourappname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/yourapplogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.yourappname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView web;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    web = new WebView(this);  
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.yourwebsite.com");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    setContentView(web);
}



public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);


    }
}

//flip screen not loading again
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(web.canGoBack()){
                web.goBack();
             }
            else
            {
                backButtonHandler();
            }
            return true;
        }

     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
public void backButtonHandler() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);


        // Setting Dialog Title
       // Setting Dialog Message

        alertDialog.setTitle("Your App Name");

  // I've included a simple dialog icon in my project named "dialog_icon", which's image file is copied and pasted in all "drawable" folders of "res" folders of the project. You can include any dialog image of your wish and rename it to dialog_icon.

        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_icon);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Exit Now?");

         // Setting Icon to Dialog
        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Exit",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
        });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
    // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

please add the INTERNET permissions in manifest.xml...

you can also view my app using webview....
http://slideme.org/application/surfen-mini