# Loading a URL by using a webview by passing URL in a second activty

Tags: android

I want to pass URL string from main activity to second activity and load the URL in second activity.... but when I click the go button at main activity it goes to second activity but it shows nothing but blank.

here is my code ..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
Button go;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

editText=findViewById(R.id.urltext);
go=findViewById(R.id.button6);

final String link=editText.getText().toString();


go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Webview.class);
        intent.putExtra("link",link);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});

}


}
```

Second Activity:

```
 public class Webview extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

String one = getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
String http="https://";
String url=http+one;

WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide your `activity_webview.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Refer these examples Please

[Web View Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

[Can someone give one exact example of webview implementation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614553/can-someone-give-one-exact-example-of-webview-implementation-in-android)

[webView android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380049/webview-android)

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be fine, just add internet permission in your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
final String link=editText.getText().toString();
```

You have made the variable "link" **final** that means this variable can be set value only once. Try putting some logs in your code and see what values are passed in the intent extra into the second activity. 
Also you have to set WebViewClient to your WebView instance.

Try below code. It worked for me:

```
private EditText editText;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urltext);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
            String link = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("link",link);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

In the second activity -

```
    private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    String one = getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
    String http="https://";
    String url=http+one;
    Log.d(WebViewActivity.class.getSimpleName(), url);
    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv_url);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

Comment: it works !! thanks, bro.it would be another help if you can tell me why i have to use  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: Sure. If you don't set the WebViewClient, then android will show a prompt  to choose the application like chrome, opera etc before loading the url. If you set the WebViewClient then the url will directly load in the WebView within your layout without any prompt.

Comment: @EmranulHaqueRakib please mark Siba's answer as correct.

Comment: I am sorry bro if could I would have done that. I don't have enough reputation to cast vote. @AxelD.

Comment: Maybe you can not up or downvote but you can mark it as the correct answer because you are the asker...no one else could ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have several buttons those I have not used yet. I have used button 6.

Activity mainXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundone"
tools:context="com.example.rakib.webbrowser.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/urltext"
    android:layout_width="250sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="italic"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
   android:background="@drawable/buttonshapehome"
    android:text="Facebook"
    android:textColor="#fdf900"
    android:textStyle="italic"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/urltext"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Youtube"
    android:textColor="#fdf900"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshapehome"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="italic"

    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Google"
    android:textStyle="italic"

    android:textColor="#fdf900"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshapehome"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshapehome"
    android:text="linkdin"
    android:textColor="#fdf900"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:textStyle="italic"

    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshapehome"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:text="gmail"
    android:textStyle="italic"

    android:textColor="#fdf900"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
     />

<Button

     android:id="@+id/newage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshapehome"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:text="new age"
    android:textStyle="italic"


    android:textColor="#fdf900"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:text="GO"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/urltext"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/urltext"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/urltext"
    android:background="#039337"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
    android:background="@drawable/settings_icon"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#ffaa00" />``

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"

    android:textColor="#ffff" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity webviewXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rakib.webbrowser.Webview">



<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="470dp">

</WebView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:src="@drawable/homeicon"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36sp"
        tools:ignore="OnClick" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reload"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/reload"
        android:layout_height="36sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="com.example.rakib.webbrowser">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

</uses-permission>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Webview">


    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```